# Deepzoom images: starting image quality

Tags: image-processing, deepzoom, openseadragon, vips

I am working on implementing a zoomable image viewer using OpenSeadragon and deep zoom images. I used the VIPS command line tool to create DZI files. My question is, does the original image used to create DZI files need to meet specific requirements to make it zoomable? (like format, size, etc.) If a normal .jpg image is converted to DZI, it seems like the image will not be zoomable. Is this correct?

Comment: not sure about that but using a compressed image format as source of a zoomable image doesn't make much sense to my. I suggest you just try different formats and sizes.

Comment: @Piglet  I tried again this time creating the DZI files from a JPEG2000 image. The image looks great in Seadragon, however, the zoom functionality is still not what we'd like. You can only zoom in one level. Is there a way to set the zoom level during conversion?  This is the VIPS command that I was running to convert to DZI: vips dzsave test.jp2 test

Answer (score 3):

> My question is, does the original image used to create DZI files need to meet specific requirements to make it zoomable?

No, except to have a resolution higher than the screen resolution (in that case, the original image can be displayed directly).